# Pass data to Call Directory Extension

Tags: ios, swift, call

I cannot pass data call directory extension from main app

1. I've created one App group and turned it on in App capabilities for both targets (main app and extension)
2. I pass data with NSUser

-Create Data in main app

```
var userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.test.callapp")
    userDefaults?.set("mynumber", forKey: "mykey")
```

-Retrieve Data in extension

```
var baseDescription =  "test"

let newUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.test.callapp")

if let testUserId = newUserDefaults?.object(forKey: "mykey") as? String 
{
baseDescription = testUserId
}
```

When i do it in only main app - everything is ok, but when i do it in extension (i do it in 'addIdentificationPhoneNumbers' function) - it doesn't work, baseDescripton doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions shoud work, the only problem I can see is that you don't have App Groups enabled (with your "group.test.callapp" group) both for your application and the extension. Check Target->Capabilities if this is enabled for both. Another caveat is to pass the phone number in the international format (with country code).